# Javascript replace error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one problem with function in Javascript. When I insert text in `textarea`, function sends text to `PHP` script with AJAX, but I have problem when I insert two or three words, e.g `Bosnia and Herzegovina` then the script does not work. I used string replace :

```js
    function provjeraDrzave(rijec) {
        rijec = rijec.replace(" ", "%20");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/drzava.php?slovo=" + randomslovo + "&drzava=" + rijec,
            success: function (odgovor) {
                $('#rezultati').replaceWith($("<span id='rezultati'>" + odgovor + "</span>"));
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Doslo je do pogreske');
            }
        });
    }
```

It should work as follows: When I insert `Bosnia and Herzegovina` that must change to `Bosnia%20and%20Herzegovina` but that change to `Bosnia%20and Herzegovina` and that does not work. Where is the problem ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use, for example, the native `encodeURIComponent` function, which is made for this?

Or, even better, let jQuery take care of URL encoding for you, using the `data` config param:

```
function provjeraDrzave(rijec) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            slovo: randomslovo,
            drzava: rijec
        },
        url: "/drzava.php",
        success: function (odgovor) {
            $('#rezultati').replaceWith($("<span id='rezultati'>" + odgovor + "</span>"));
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Doslo je do pogreske');
        }
     });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) can receive url arguments via the `data` property and should automatically serialize it for you.

> #### data
>
> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests... Object must be Key/Value pairs...

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/drzava.php'
    data : {
        'slovo' : randomslovo,
        'drzava' : rijec          //no need  to replace
    }
    success: function (returndata) {...},
    error: function () {...}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely want to do this way try

```
rijec = rijec.replace(/\ /g, "%20");
```

but `encodeURIComponent` would be more appropriate.